# python flask script update heroku db

Tags: python, database, flask, heroku, scheduled-tasks

I have a flask app deployed on Heroku right now. I wrote a script to update the database everyday and scheduled it to run everyday using Heroku Scheduler. The script runs fine but I am finding that it is not updating the database.

To deploy my app I have a wsgi.py

```
from my_project import create_app

app = create_app()
```

My Procfile

```
web: gunicorn wsgi:app
```

My script just imports a function I have in my init.py which looks like this:

```
def job(app):
    with app.app_context():
         # update database and execute job
```

My script:

```
from wsgi import app
from my_project import job

job(app)
```

My question is why the db is not updating. Is it because I have the app_context? So am I updating the db, but not in the correct context? Is it correct to import the app from wsgi.py? Is it the correct app that is being used in Heroku?

Comment: If you were to take out the scheduler aspect of your app then perform a build to heroku and opened it, did it work as expected?

Comment: Yes it works. Only when the scheduler runs the script, the db does not update